# Can clang-format break my code?

Tags: c, clang-format

As `clang-format` is a tool to only reformat code, is it possible that such formatting can break working code or at least change how it works? Is there some kind of contract that it will/can not change how code works?

We have a lot of code that we want to format with `clang-format`. This means, many lines of code will change. Not having to review every single line of code that only changed due to a `clang-format` would be a big simplification of this process.

I would say that `clang-format` will not change how code works. On the other hand I am not 100% sure, if this can be guaranteed.

Comment: If clang-format broke valid code it'd be pretty useless, don't you think?

Comment: @EOF, agreed, but can you *guarantee* that clang-format is bug-free? :)

Comment: @rici: As I understand it, it uses clang's parser to make sure it keeps the semantics intact. Can you *guarantee* that clang won't break your code during a normal compile?

Comment: Are the executables the same?

Comment: @rici Can you _guarantee_ that Linux is bug-free? (Windows, OS X, whatever do you run)

Comment: @EOF: No, I can't. A more relevant question is whether I can guarantee that a future version of clang would parse my program in a different way which changes program behaviour; I can't guarantee that, either. (And, actually, it happens from time to time, but more commonly with optimization than with parsing.) "Guarantee" is a very strong word.

Comment: @EOF *"Can you guarantee that clang won't break your code during a normal compile?"* Given that clang opens the source file for reading only, yes, I can guarantee it won't damage it :-)

Comment: Actually, my point (which I could have made more clearly) is that a program with bugs is not necessarily "useless". If the bugs are triggered by circumstances so unlikely that no-one has yet noticed them, the program might still be widely used by people who find it useful. Even if the bugs are not so obscure, I might find the program useful, as in @Anton's example.

Comment: Also, I think @WeatherVane's question is the key, here. If you compile the original and the reformatted programs and the resulting executables are the same, then you can be confident that there were no semantic changes. Although personally I find it unlikely that you would ever find a bug of this nature in clang-format, if you are working in a context which requires extraordinary paranoia, that test would be simple enough to perform.

Comment: @rici: Which is the reason we test our software at various levels. But that is just hypothetically relevant for the question.

Comment: And if your project is a header-only library, or header files are shipped as well, then checking the binaries won't be enough, you also need good coverage tests... Which is why we test our software at various levels ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That's true. Really, a test can only provide more confidence; there is always some possibility of error. Suppose, for example, that some compiler being used has a whitespace-handling bug which is triggered by the correct reformatting done by clang-format. (eg. a bug in stringification which results in changing a string literal).

Comment: @eof This is a good question in my opinion. Several of the clang-tidy plugins I have tried broke my code, and they are pretty useless. I'd expect a higher standard from clang-format as it's more of a core tool and more widely used (and I found no bug reports when I searched), but nevertheless I'm researching this question prior to applying clang-format to a large code base.

Comment: It depends (on your format configuration), I used the uncrustify code format tool a long time and no issues caused by formatting. It seems the clang-format used the kinds of style templates, that should be the same I think.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## Short answer: YES.

---

The `clang-format` tool has a `-sort-includes` option. Changing the order of `#include` directives can definitely change the behavior of existing code, and ***may break existing code.***

Since the corresponding `SortIncludes` option is set to `true` by several of the built-in styles, it might not be obvious that `clang-format` is going to reorder your includes.

**MyStruct.h:**

```
struct MyStruct {
    uint8_t value;
};
```

**original.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "MyStruct.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct MyStruct s = { 0 };
    return s.value;
}
```

Now let's say we run `clang-format -style=llvm original.c > restyled.c`.

**restyled.c:**

```
#include "MyStruct.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct MyStruct s = {0};
  return s.value;
}
```

Due to the reordering of the header files, I get the following error when compiling `restyled.c`:

```
In file included from restyled.c:1:
./MyStruct.h:2:5: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
    uint8_t value;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

However, this issue should be easy to work around. It's unlikely that you have order-dependent includes like this, but if you do, you can fix the problem by putting a blank line between groups of headers that require a specific order, since apparently `clang-format` only sorts groups of `#include` directives with no non-`#include` lines in between.

**fixed-original.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include "MyStruct.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct MyStruct s = { 0 };
    return s.value;
}
```

**fixed-restyled.c:**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "MyStruct.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct MyStruct s = {0};
  return s.value;
}
```

Note that `stdint.h` and `stddef.h` were still reordered since their includes are still "grouped", but that the new blank line prevented `MyStruct.h` from being moved before the standard library includes.

---

## However...

If reordering your `#include` directives breaks your code, you should probably do one of the following anyway:

1. Explicitly include the dependencies for each header in the header file. In my example, I'd need to include `stdint.h` in `MyStruct.h`.
2. Add a comment line between the include groups that explicitly states the ordering dependency.  Remember that any non-`#include` line should break up a group, so comment lines work as well. The comment line in the following code also prevents `clang-format` from including `MyStruct.h` before the standard library headers.

**alternate-original.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
// must come after stdint.h
#include "MyStruct.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct MyStruct s = { 0 };
    return s.value;
}
```

Comment: I like the answer, because it also tells you how to fix your includes in the first place. Clang IWYU can be our friend here

Comment: There's also the fact that there may be bugs in clang-format that causes it to break code during formatting. I have never experienced that, but the risk is there.

Comment: I would add advice #3:  if possible modify your headers so that their behavior does not depend on the order they are #included — or at least causes a compile-time error if they are included “wrong”.  Otherwise you have left a banana-peel for every junior developer to slip and fall on :)

Answer (score 12):

For sure it can change how your code works. And the reason is C program can view some properties of its source code. What I'm thinking about is `__LINE__` macro, but I'm not sure there are no other ways.

Consider `1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("%d\n", __LINE__);}
```

Then:

```
> clang 1.c -o 1.exe & 1.exe
2
```

Now do some `clang-format`:

```
> clang-format -style=Chromium 1.c >2.c
```

And `2.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
}
```

And, of course, output has changed:

```
> clang 2.c -o 2.exe & 2.exe
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `clang-format` affects only whitespace characters, you can check that files before and after `clang-format`ing are identical up to  whitespaces. In Linux/BSD/OS X you can use `diff` and `tr` for that:

```
$ diff --ignore-all-space <(tr '\n' ' ' < 2.c ) <(tr '\n' ' ' < 1.c)
```

1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {printf("Hello, world!\n"); return 0;}
```

2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of `diff` command is empty, meaning that files `1.c` and `2.c` are identical up to whitespaces.

As [Karoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650405/karoly-horvath) mentioned in his comment, note that in ideal conditions you still have to check spaces that matters, e.g. string literals. But in the real world I believe this test is more than enough.

Comment: Great idea, though technically you still have to check the whitespaces that matter (strings).

Comment: The other whitespace that matters is the newline that terminates a preprocessor directive.  There's also whitespace that separates alphanumeric tokens - `else if` is not `elseif` - but we'll assume it doesn't break those.  In both cases, you should expect a syntax error rather than a subtle change of semantics.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: unfamiliar as I am with clang-format, surely its writers thought of string literals?

Comment: There's also `#define foo(bar)` versus `#define foo (bar)` and a number of other issues such as `__LINE__` changing if newlines get inserted or deleted.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is not sufficient to test whether the code is equivalent, but I agree it goes most of the way. In practise, you need to add two more characters: double quotes (because clang-format splits up very long strings) and backslashes (because clang-format reformats macros, where a backslash is required for newlines). So `tr '\n'` => `tr '\\\n"'`.

Comment: I believe "affects only whitespace" is not entirely true, since it can break long strings, introducing additional quotes. `clang-format-5` can also introduce comments at namespace closing braces, i.e. `} // namespace foo`.

Answer (score 3):

clang-format reformatted ASM code in a project because we effectively did this:

```
#define ASM _asm

ASM {

  ...

}
```

Comment: This is helpful because changes in a `.h` file dealing with assembly code can break things.

Answer (score 1):

**yes**

**it will not break the working flow**

the system has the config switch:
**"C_Cpp.clang_format_sortIncludes": false**,
but it not work, i don't know what is wrong...

my version is:ms-vscode.cpptools-0.13.1

this is my solution:

for the stable working flow ,use the grammar:

// clang-format off

...here is your code

// clang-format on

Answer (score 0):

It can break your code, if you use special constructs in your code and your settings for formatting.

**Inline Assembler**

If you normally compile your code with gcc and make use of gcc-style inline assembler, clang-format will very likely break the naming of register variables, as it sees the %-character as an operator.

```
asm_movq(%[val2], %%mm0)
```

will be reformatted as

```
asm_movq(% [val2], % % mm0)
```

which will no longer compile.

**Constructing a Path in a macro**

If you build up a path using macros without using strings, clang-format again will see the '/' character as an operator and will put spaces around it.

Boost e.g. uses a construct like this:

```
#   define AUX778076_PREPROCESSED_HEADER \
    BOOST_MPL_CFG_COMPILER_DIR/BOOST_MPL_PREPROCESSED_HEADER
```

to construct a path to a header file. The '/' is not an operator here, but as it is not inside a string, clang-format treats it as an operator and puts spaces around it, creating a different path.
The include of the header file will obviously fail.

**Conclusion**

Yes, clang-format *can* break your code. If you are using very specific constructs that are edge cases or outside of the language standard or simply extensions of your very specific compiler (which is not clang), then you will need to check the changes made by clang-format. Otherwise you risk getting hidden errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately. After years of using `clang-format`, today I faced [this issue](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49868). My use case was similar to the one described in the bug:

```
int main() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  return x < y - 1 >> 1;
}
```

can be reformatted as:

```
int main() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  return x < y - 1 > > 1; /*<< Code is broken*/
}
```

Luckily, it's been fixed, and the tool update helped!

Answer (score -5):

I imagine it would not, given that it is built on clang's static analysis, and therefore has knowledge of the structure of code itself, rather than just a dumb source code formatter that operates on the text alone(one of the boons of being able to use a compiler library).  Given that the formatter uses the same parser and lexer as the compiler itself, I'd feel safe enough that it wouldn't have any issue spitting out code that behaves the same as what you feed it.

You can see the source code for the C++ formatter here: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Format_8cpp_source.html

Comment: Several clang-tidy plugins break code, but are built on clang's static analysis, use the same technology as the compiler itself, etc.