# Can I run clang-format on codebases that cannot be compiled with clang?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Given some C++ features are supported on GCC but not Clang, it's possible for my codebase to compile with GCC, but not clang.

As per title, would there be any issues with running clang-format on said codebase?

Tried running clang-format on my codebase and everything seems to work. However, I want to be very sure that I'm not missing anything.

Comment: You're probably not going to get overwhelming responses because "would there be any issues" is an ambiguous question and what constitutes an "issue" is very vague.

Comment: Your code does not need to (be able to) compile with Clang to run Clang Format on your codebase. Orthogonally, yes clang format has a non-zero chance of introducing breaking changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927553/can-clang-format-break-my-code

Comment: Just try - why don't you?

Comment: @JesperJuhl “just try it” seems like dangerous advice when applied to a procedure that rewrites your source code … in particular the hazard is that a runtime bug might be surreptitiously introduced by incorrect handling, and then cost the developer lots of time and/or customer goodwill to detect and fix.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "Just try" and "commit to prod" are not the same thing. Try it, run the full suite of tests on it, maybe even give a build to QA if they have time.

Comment: @sweenish empirical testing only gets you so far -- it's always a good idea to read the instructions and make sure the tool is actually designed to do what you are using it for, otherwise you can fall into the trap of "it seems to work okay", right up until it doesn't.

Comment: clang-format is a whitespace manager. I've found that macros are usually the things that get screwed up, and only if they were poorly written from the get-go. In any case, we proved idempotency by using a deterministic build process. clang-format also had to be run 5 times before it it stopped making changes to the code. But that was a one-off.

Comment: If we were talking about clang-tidy, your argument would have a lot more merit.

Comment: No software is perfect, even if it compiles with clang some bugs sometimes introduce into clang-format that break code.  For example, a current one in 15.0.6 is this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-15236/Support-custom-clang-format-binary#focus=Comments-27-6690483.0-0  which introduces a compile-time error with attributes, introducing whitespace breaking the double-bracket into two single brackets.

Answer (score 0):

A formatter (such as clang-format) doesn't need to compile the source in order to format it. As such, clang-format may work on source that cannot be compiled by clang.

However, some language features are significant syntactical additions to the language (such as function attributes and lambdas have been). If the formatter hasn't been updated to handle such syntax change, then it may fail to work, or it may produce an undesirable format.